# How to make 3 thumbnails in two rows slider (scroller)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this scroller(slider)

[thumbnails slider code](http://bit.ly/1s9wJ4Y)

I'd like to show 6 thumbnails (instead of 3) , 3 per row (2 rows), and whenever someone slides it shows the next 6 thumbnails..

[image: That's what i'm trying to reach]

I've tried a lot but I didn't succeed.

Thank you so much, appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

**Now define this css**

```
.advancedscroller {
    overflow:hidden;
}

body .advancedscroller .arrowsCon > .arrow-left,
body .advancedscroller .arrowsCon > .arrow-right{
    top:50%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwwdedrr/9/)**